# @JmsListener throwing MessageConversionException

Tags: spring-webflux, ibm-mq, spring-jms, reactor, spring-dsl

I'm trying to receive a message asynchronously from IBM MQ:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "queue", containerFactory = "Factory", id = "start")
    public Mono<Void> requestProcess(Message message) {return Mono.just("").then();  
}
```

Catch:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert object of type [reactor.core.publisher.MonoLift] to JMS message. Supported message payloads are: String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object.
```

If I switch method type to simple `void` it works as supposed to. How can I set listener to receive messages in non-blocking reactive way?

Comment: If @chughts answer helped you please accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion that is failing is the input to `requestProcess`.

`@JmsListener` has a found a publisher of type `reactor.core.publisher.MonoLift`, but `requestProcess` is expecting a `Message`, and it doesn't have a conversion.

The way round this would be to changed the input signature for `requestProcess` to

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "queue", containerFactory = "Factory", id = "start")
    public Mono<Void> requestProcess(MonoLift<?> publisher) {
       ...

    }
```

and modify the method body accordingly.